# combinations without repetition then split result into groups of unique elements

Tags: python

I have a list of X elements. I need to produce all possible combinations (without repetition) and put these items into groups of unique elements. Number of elements in groups should be declarative. For example if I have a list of 4 elements and want to have 2 items per group it would look like that:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

all combinations

```
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 4
```

and my groups

```
group 1
1 2
3 4

group 2
1 3
2 4

group 3
1 4
2 3
```

The easy part is done

```
from itertools import combinations 

all_items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
cm = list(combinations(all_items, 2))

print('total combinations [{}]: {}'.format(len(cm), cm))
```

but what would be solution for the rest of this task?

Comment: how r you deciding groups?

Comment: groups will be decided automatically as they are determined by items in them. In my example above I wanted to have 2 items per groups which gave me 3 groups in total.

Comment: For 3 variables, `total combinations [10]: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]` how do you want the groups to be?

Comment: There are many possibilities. If I decide that each group should have 2 items, then I will endup with 5 groups. If i decide to have 3 items in each group i will endup with 3 groups with 3 items and 1 group with 1 item, right?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat bruteforcy. Goes through all combinations and assigns based on whether the elements of a given tuple are not already in the list.

```
items_per_group= 2
groups = [[] for _ in range(int(len(cm)/items_per_group))]

while len(cm)>0:

    a = cm.pop(0)

    for group in groups:

        # create flattened list and check if all elements of tuple are absent
        current_entries = list(chain.from_iterable(group))

        if not sum([x in current_entries for x in a]):
            group.append(a)
            break
```

testcases:

```
all_items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
items_per_group = 2

print(groups)
[[(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(1, 3), (2, 4)], [(1, 4), (2, 3)]]

all_items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
items_per_group = 3

print(groups)
[[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)],
 [(1, 2, 4), (3, 5, 6)],
 [(1, 2, 5), (3, 4, 6)],
 [(1, 2, 6), (3, 4, 5)],
 [(1, 3, 4), (2, 5, 6)],
 [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]]
```

Comment: Hmmm, almost there but when I wrote 'items' I had something else in mind: Group 1 would then have 3 positions with 2 items in each, like: group1-> (1,2) (3,4) (5,6)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def grouper(cm, num):
    """ num -> implies the max num of elems in a group """
    no_groups = math.ceil(len(cm)/num)
    keys, vals = cm[:no_groups], cm[no_groups:]
    for tup in keys:
        valid_cms = filter(lambda x:len({*x,*tup})==4,vals)
        groups = [tup]
        for _ in range(num-1):
            if vals:groups.append(vals.pop(0))
        print(groups)
cm = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]
grouper(cm,4)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
[(1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5)]
[(1, 4), (4, 5)]
```

```
>>> cm = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
>>> grouper(cm,4)
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
[(1, 3), (3, 4)]

>>> grouper(cm,2)
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(1, 3), (2, 4)]
[(1, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: what would be equivalent of this line valid_cms = filter(lambda x:len({*x,*tup})==4,vals) for python2? I forgot to mention that i'm still using python2

Comment: This will probably work: `filter(lambda x:len(set(x) - set(tup))==2,vals)